# Why does implicit conversion from sql_variant (basetype decimal) not work well with float

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion, cast, sql-variant-property

Why is ResultFloat = 0 in the query below?

Am I missing a point within the [cast/convert](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), [sql_variant](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx) docs?

```
declare
    @v sql_variant = convert(decimal(28,8), 20.0);

select sql_variant_property(@v, 'BaseType') as BaseType,         -- 'decimal',
       iif(convert(int, 10.0)     < @v, 1, 0) as ResultInt,      -- 1
       iif(convert(decimal, 10.0) < @v, 1, 0) as  ResultDecimal, -- 1
       iif(convert(float, 10.0)   < @v, 1, 0) as  ResultFloat,   -- 0 !
       iif(convert(float, 10.0)   < convert(float, @v), 1, 0) as  ResultFloatFloat,  -- 1              
       iif(convert(float, 10.0)   < convert(decimal(28,8), @v), 1, 0) as  ResultFloatDecimal;   -- 1
```

Sql Server 2012

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [sql_variant (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173829.aspx)

> When sql_variant values of different base data types are compared and
>   the base data types are in different data type families, the value
>   whose data type family is higher in the hierarchy chart is considered
>   the greater of the two values.

The base data type family for `@v` is Exact numeric and the base data type family for `convert(float, 10.0)` is Approximate numeric.

Approximate numeric is higher up in the hierarchy chart than Exact numeric so when you compare two sql_variant values where one is Approximate numeric and the other is Exact numeric the Approximate numeric value will always be considered greater.

The full hierarchy order is

```
+---------------------+------------------+
|  Data type family   |     Members      |
+---------------------+------------------+
| sql_variant         | sql_variant      |
+---------------------+------------------+
| Date and time       | datetime2        |
|                     | datetimeoffset   |
|                     | datetime         |
|                     | smalldatetime    |
|                     | date             |
|                     | time             |
+---------------------+------------------+
| Approximate numeric | float            |
|                     | real             |
+---------------------+------------------+
| Exact numeric       | decimal          |
|                     | money            |
|                     | smallmoney       |
|                     | bigint           |
|                     | int              |
|                     | smallint         |
|                     | tinyint          |
|                     | bit              |
+---------------------+------------------+
| Unicode             | nvarchar         |
|                     | nchar            |
|                     | varchar          |
|                     | char             |
+---------------------+------------------+
| Binary              | varbinary        |
|                     | binary           |
+---------------------+------------------+
| Uniqueidentifier    | uniqueidentifier |
+---------------------+------------------+
```